# Atlassian Confluence batch.css blocked by CheckPoint R75 firewall

Tags: css, security, confluence, firewall

Our internal firewall is blocking Confluence's `batch.css`. The error message is:

> security scanner detected

I know that batch.css is made from all other CSS files. I found that icons.css and icons-min.css files are blocked when requesting them individually e.g. /includes/css/icons.css. The only interesting thing inside that CSS file are some base64 encoded GIF and PNG images.

Has anyone experienced this issue? We are running Confluence 5.